# Opposite of r.carve in QGIS - r.wall or r.dam?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, hydrology

I wonder if there is a way to perform an operation similar to r.carve, but instead of carving in the stream based on the low elevation on the extremes of a line, it fills a barrier based on the high elevation of the extremes of a line.
The purpose is hydrology, to play with the streams to change the stream network.

Comment: Did you try to just use a negative value for the `depth` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I would:

1. digitize (as a vector) the line that you want to carve
2. and give it an attribute column "height" with the value you want to add as a barrier
3. Then convert to raster, where the height column is used to set the raster cell values. (all other cells will be null)
4. You need to use `r.null` to set all other cells to zero (instead of
   NULL)
5. and finally use `r.mapcalc` to add it to the elevation raster.

Comment: The nice part of r.carve is that it reads the elevation data at both ends, so it gives us a bit more than just defining a height of a digitized line

Comment: I though about i) inverting the elevation (negative elevations), ii) perform the r.carve and iii) inverting back the result of elevation. I think it should work, but I am always struggling with the raster malipulation, so I have not tried